# paypal standard checkout redirects to paypal.com/webapps/hermes

Tags: paypal

We have set the form URL for PayPal standard checkout to https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr. When we test it from India, it works fine. All the data passed to PayPal is also displayed over there. But when we try the same from UK, it redirects to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=, which is not the URL we set in the form. The data passed was missing.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because the amount was below 4 pound (which was a test price). When i set a price above 4 pound, it works fine.

Comment: This happens for me even with the amount $ 70.00. Have you any idea about this?